# Split regular expression into 2 capture groups

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

Ok, my previous questions were answered ... I have one more, this one is more difficult for me...

```
^([A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.domain\.com)$
```

Right now this expression produces only 1 capture group as noted with ^() ; How would I do 2 capture groups for this URL? (for IIS regular expression rewrite)

Comment: What do you want to grab from the string? Post an example, and what you want to get out of it.

Comment: Ok, you haven't answered my question. Please post an example of the text to parse, and explain which portions of it you want to match.

Comment: oh sry. ---    I want to grab ie.   silverspring.md.domain.com   and capture group example: {c:1} silverspring   {c2} md

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by enclosing the relevant portions like so:

```
text    = "city.state.domain.com"
pattern = "^([^\.]+).([^\.]+).([^\.]+).([^\.]+)$"
match   = re.match(pattern, text)
match.groups()
# Returns: [ 'city', 'state', 'domain', 'com' ]
```

Comment: Note, BTW, that I made the simplifying assumption that you can have any possible values between the '.' characters. Also, in the future, you can always just split() on '.'.